# Best way to pass in a React component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, design-patterns

I was hoping to get some advice for best practices / design patterns to use to pass in a component into another component.  My example is, I have a page that has a list component which iterates through a map and renders an items detail component.  I would like to reuse this list component but when it's on different pages, render the data with different item details components.  The one requirement is that, the child component takes in the list item as props and renders it.

My second question is, this child component has a button to delete itself.  Should this be a callback function passed in from the "page" component or the list component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first part of question I suggest to use children props (this called [composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) in official documentation).

For example

```
function MyPage () {
    return <MyList>
        <MyItem name='item1'/>
        <MyItem name='item2'/>
    </MyList>
}
```

And `MyList` component will look like

```
function MyList (props) {
    return <div>This is list!
        {props.children}
    </div>
}
```

`props.children` will contain all elements which are present between `<MyList>` and `</MyList>` tags. (In above example they are `<MyItem name='item1'/>` and `<MyItem name='item2'/>`). You can also manipulate childrens props from `MyList` component using [React.children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren).

For second part of your question, in general state should be [lifted up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). This approach helps in most cases. How high it should be moved depends on several factors. For example, if you will query list items from backend and pass modified list to backend, this can be done in `MyList` component. But if you'll use list items in other components, for example in left side menu, to show favorites, it can be a good idea to lift state higher to `Page` component.

Comment: Hey!  Thank you!  This is exactly what I was looking for and helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If the item detail components are all identical in terms of what props they take, then the simplest approach would be to pass the component type as a prop to the list.

In terms of the second question, there's no golden rule, it's whatever really makes sense with your components. Based on what you've described though, it sounds like your list component should be a [container](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005), and should manage the deletes (possibly also the loading as well) e.g.

```
const AnchorListItem = ({ onDelete, id, text }) => (
  <li>
    <a data-id={id} onClick={onDelete}>{text}</a>
  </li>
);
const ButtomListItem = ({ onDelete, id, text }) => (
  <li>
    <button data-id={id} onClick={onDelete}>{text}</button>
  </li>
);
class List extends React.Component {
  handleDeleteItem = e => {
    // Delete item (you can grab ID from e.target.dataset.id)
  }
  render() {
    const { data, component: Item } = this.props;
    const items = data.map((x, i) => <Item key={i} {...x} onDelete={handleDeleteItem} />);
    return <ul>{items}</ul>;
  }
};
const PageA = () => <List component={AnchorListItem} data={...} />;
const PageB = () => <List component={ButtonListItem} data={...} />;
```